# Pinia modify/add action via plugin

Tags: typescript, pinia

I'm trying to create a plugin for pinia in order to modify/add an action. In the store I have:

```
export const useStore = defineStore('store', {
  state: ...,
  actions: { 
       actionToModify(param: string) {}
  }
})
```

Then I don't know how to modify this action. In the Vue.js file where I want to modify it, I tried something like this (but I think it's pretty stupid):

```
pinia.use(({ options }) => {
  options.actions.actionToModify = (param) => console.log(param); 
})
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help:

`pinia.use(({ store }) => { store.actionToModify = (param) => console.log(param);  })`

Comment: well, the problem is that actions created on the fly doesn't seems to trigger the $onAction hook